# three js - objects facing screen as a billboard

Tags: javascript, three.js, particles

Three particles works as billboards always facing the screen. Since I'm using an animated texture on a plane mesh, I'd like to simulate that effect without using particles.
I tried to do:

```
obj.lookAt(camera.position);
obj.up = camera.up;
```

But, that doesn't really do what I was trying to achieve. Since that way obj is not parallel to the screen. I guess I have to project/unproject coordinates but didn't really get how to do that.

What's the best way to achieve it?